# Insert data from one table into another using SQL

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a **postcode centres** table created from a shapefile and a **census data** table that is a CSV with postcodes. I need to add the census data columns to the postcode centres table. I would normally join them in QGIS based on the postcode and create the columns that way, but the files are too big and QGIS keeps crashing. So I've uploaded them into PostGIS and I am now trying to run a sql query on the data via the DB Manager plugin.

My data is in PostGIS accessed though QGIS 2.14. I'm very new to SQL.

```
INSERT INTO postcode_centres 
(total_pop, males_pop, females_pop, occupied_house_pop)
   (SELECT postcode_census.total, postcode_census.males, 
    postcode_census.females, postcode_census.occupied_house FROM postcode_census
WHERE postcode_centres.postcode = postcode_census.postcode);
```

Comment: Are you trying to insert new rows to your table `postcode_centres` or do you want to add data columns to existing features?

Comment: I would like to add columns to existing festures

Comment: There is no GIS-centric problem here -- It's still a SQL syntax issue. When you write to [dba.se], you'll want to distinguish between a desire to `INSERT` rows and `UPDATE` columns. Providing SQL definitions of the tables (`CREATE TABLE ...`) and a graphic that helps explain your goal will be helpful. A little research into the difference between INSERT and UPDATE (and their very different syntax) might solve your problem directly.

Answer (score 1):

Your select statement needs to run properly which will need to include a join between the two tables and also there's no table called 'females' so femails.postcode will not work - assuming you meant postcode_census.postcode, the SQL might look like this:

```
INSERT INTO postcode_centres 
(total_pop, males_pop, females_pop, occupied_house_pop)

   (

   SELECT postcode_census.total, postcode_census.males, 
    postcode_census.females, postcode_census.occupied_house 

FROM postcode_census as a 
join postcode_centers as b 
on  postcode_centers.postcode = postcode_census.postcode

);
```

Comment: Sorry about the females error, I typed that out wrong. When I used the join I am still get this error:  
LINE 5:     ON postcode_centres.postcode = postcode_census.postcode

Comment: does the SELECT query work on its own before you put it into the INSERT statement?

Comment: For a slightly cleaner syntax, if the join-columns are the same, you can do `USING (postcode)`

Comment: No the select statement doesn't work.
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "postcode_censes"
LINE 4:  ON postcode_centres.postcode = postcode_censes.postcode
                                        ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "postcode_censes"
SQL state: 42P01
Character: 188

Comment: get that select statement to work first then your insert should be fine...